# Assembly offset calculation rule

Tags: assembly, x86, offset, x86-16

So... the rule of offset calculation states in my course book that:

```
offset = [bp] + [bx] + [di|si] + CONST  (any part is optional, but atleast one is required)
```

But reading on the internet i found the rule as :

```
offset = [bp|bx] + [di|si] + CONST
```

**Which one is it? And why?**

(In my opinion the first should be also  valid since bx could contain an arbitrary value like (1..F), but i tend to belive I am wrong and  there must be a BX or BP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "internet rule" is correct. You can have 1 base register (`bp` or `bx`) and 1 index register (`si` or `di`). You can't have `bp + bx` or `si + di` at the same time. See *Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* in the [Intel Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

Your course book is however correct that any part is optional but at least one is required, so you don't need a base or an index or an offset. These are all valid: `[const]`, `[bx]`, `[si]`, `[bx + si]`, `[bp + di + const]`. The full  list is in the manual I linked above.

Comment: Note that using bp as a base register changes the default segment used for the reference from ds to ss.