# Assembly String Building

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I have been fighting this for so long. I am trying to build a string in x86 Assembly. Here is my situation: I have a string that is empty, and whenever the program moves right, i need to put r on the string. If the program moves down, I need to put d on the string. So once it is fully executed, the string would equal: rrdddrd Or something like that. But my issue is that I can't move the string index correctly. Here is what I am trying:

```
mov ax, index
mov finalString+ax, "r"
```

Where index is a WORD and finalString is a BYTE of 40 `finalString BYTE 40 DUP (0)`

Here is my error:

```
error A2032: invalid use of register
```

So I my syntax is incorrect. Can anyone help me figure this out? I am using a cmp je loop right now to build the string.

Comment: Which statement is giving the error?

Comment: In real mode, you can't index using `ax`.

Comment: I figured that. So how can I index the string?

Comment: The statement is posted above that is giving the error

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561487/assembly-offset-calculation-rule). TL;DR: use for example `bx` instead of `ax`.

Comment: I guess I am just not understanding because using `bx` instead still gives me the invalid use of register

Comment: According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax0tswaz.aspx) the cause of this error is `Brackets ([ ]) were missing around a register that was added to something.`. Thus, use `mov [finalString+bx], "r"`. Also be aware that `"r"` itself might not be valid, so you might need to write something like `mov byte ptr [finalString+bx], 'r'`

Comment: If you would gladly put an answer below. I will select it as best answer! Thanks a ton