# move the values from data segment via offset

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I have data segment

```
dataseg segment para 'data'
var1 db 3 
var2 db 5 
dataseg ends
```

i'm trying to move the values, i.e.

```
mov ax, offset var2
mov bx, [ax]
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561487/assembly-offset-calculation-rule). For future reference, "doesn't work" is not a good problem description, you should specify exactly what happens. In this case the assembler probably gave you an error message saying that's invalid address. That should have prompted you to check what the valid addressing modes are in a reference manual, and could have fixed the problem yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly offset calculation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561487/assembly-offset-calculation-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 16-bit real mode, `ax` is not allowed to be used between brackets (as a base register), but `bx` is:

```
mov bx, offset var2  ;◄■■ BX INSTEAD OF AX.
mov ax, [bx]
```

Only `bx` and `bp` can be used in this way as base registers when addressing memory. `ax` is generally used to store/accumulate values for other purposes.

By the way, your variables are size "byte", but you are moving their value into a size "word" register. You can fix it in two ways:

```
var1 DW 3     ;◄■■ USE A WORD SIZE VARIABLE.
```

or

```
mov al, [bx]  ;◄■■ USE A BYTE SIZE REGISTER.
```

Comment: Ok, but im getting  mov bx,002 instead mov bx,102 via offset var2

Comment: @demsee, I don't understand, would you explain a little better : are you moving 002 or 102 into bx?

Comment: ou, i just foggot to use @data

Comment: @demsee, are you sure TASM is not complaining about the line `mov bx, [ax]`?

Comment: @demsee, so my answer is correct, shouldn't it be accepted (you know, by clicking on the ✔) ? ^_º